# is proxy server behind VPN trackable?

Tags: vpn, proxy, http

[image]

Hi there, I have this interesting question. HTTP communication goes from PC to Proxy server, then proxy server is connected to VPN server, and from VPN server data goes to internet. Can anyone in internet identify, that in this line is used  proxy server?

I know, when I ommit VPN server, proxy server is easily detectable.
Thank you!

Comment: Um...are VPN and proxy servers local or remote?

Comment: proxy server is in local LAN. VPN server is remote.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if the proxy-server adds a HTTP header `X-Forwarded-For`, most of them do. Proxy can also add several other headers, depends of the actual software.

Comment: I found out that for example Squid can be set to disable these headers.